# How to make svg RTL

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I want to make `svg` RTL, meaning i want to change the origin from 'Top Left' to 'Top Right' in a way that when i say draw a path `M 0 0 L 100 100`, it creates a line that starts with `top: 0, right: 0` and goes to `top: 100, right: 100`
I tried most common solution for changing origin but none of them work as i want it to
My code:

```html
<svg
  style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", textAlign: "right" }}
  //preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet"
>
    <path stroke="green" strokeWidth="3" fill="none" d="M 0 0 L 100 100" />
</svg>
```

[And here is a working example of the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sun-2zhcm?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate and scale the canvas, though be warned any text will display RTL too.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
      <g transform="translate(200, 0) scale(-1, 1)">
        <path stroke="green" strokeWidth="3" fill="none" d="M 0 0 L 100 100" />
      </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: My width and height are both `100%` and they have to be, how can i do this transformation with width and height `100%` ?

Comment: `<g transform="translate(100%,100%) scale(-1, 1)">` doesn't work

Comment: I managed to fix this by importing the `css` as module and the giving it to `<g>` as a `className`, this way i was able to use `transform="translate(100%,0) scale(-1, 1)"`

Comment: you'd probably just use a viewBox. Note that you can't use units with transform as an attribute.