# Transform is not triggered again on window resize

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

Following on [How to make svg RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579169/how-to-make-svg-rtl/58579204?noredirect=1#comment103474435_58579204)
I made my svg RTL using:

```
transform: translate(100%, 0) scale(-1, 1);
```

But when i try resizing my browser window, the `transform` is not applied and the line origin changes!
[Here is an example showing this issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-origin-change-testcase-lshzh?fontsize=14)
To replicate:
1- Change the windows size (maybe make it bigger), you can see that the line origin doesn't stay on `0 0`
2- Use inspect element on the line, uncheck and then check the "transform" in the css class, the element is returned to its intended position

By doing what i described it is obvious that the transform is not applied on resize.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) to define the position and dimension of an SVG viewport:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        Please resize the browser window, as you can see the line doesnt remain
        on 0, 0
      </div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke">
        <g className="svgRTL">
          <path
            stroke="green"
            strokeWidth="3"
            fill="none"
            d="M 0 0 L 100 100"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58580581-viewBox]

Comment: I see, so using viewBox solves this! thanks, can i make the viewBox `width: 100% height: 100%` ?

Comment: `svg` has `width`,`height` attributes, use it as you like: `<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%">` the default values are `auto`

Comment: I'm using `svg` along side `div`, to create something like a workflow diagram, when i give the `svg` a `viewBox`, it causes the lines to have their thickness changed on resize, and it also ruins the rest of the program since i used absolute position for the whole thing, what are my options ?

Comment: Is there a way to not use viewBox and yet trigger the transformation ?, because without viewBox everything works except on resize

Comment: Use a `viewBox` for example `viewBox="0 0 200 100"` and to preserve the same line width use `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

Comment: I guess it because of `scale(-1,1)`, you can lower the viewBox (depending on the path implementation and remove the scale), you should ask another question with a reproducible example because it is too abstract to try answering like this.

Comment: @enxaneta Your solution meaning `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` fixed my problem, thanks!